# Rails ERB optlabel is having issues with a space in the label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have the following code

```
<% optgroup_label = "May 2017" %>
<optgroup label= <%= optgroup_label %> >
```

It's producing the following HTML

```
<optgroup label="May" 2017>
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue? I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Forgot to add a few things.
I'm using rails 4.2.0 with 
ruby 2.3.0

Answer (score 3):

Simple fix for this one, even though `optgroup_label` is a string, you still need to wrap it in quotes in the html

```
<% optgroup_label = "May 2017" %>
<optgroup label="<%= optgroup_label %>">
```

and that produces `<optgroup label="May 2017">` instead of `<optgroup label="May" 2017="">`